# SSH into ec2 instance with ansible not working. Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, permission-denied

I am following an ansible tutorial and trying to run ad hoc ansible command but I am getting a permission denied error. My controller (local machine) is wsl ubuntu and the node is amazon linux 2023. I used the AWS UI to generate the access keys and I can reach my node via ssh with no issues.

The command I am trying to run is

```
ansible all -i inventory -m ping
```

but when I run it, I am getting

```
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

my inventory file is:

```
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

And my ansible.cfg file is:

```
private_key_file=~/.ssh/path/to/private/key
```

I've tried moving around where the put the 'private_key_file'. I've had it in the inventory file itself and also in the etc/ansible/ansible.cfg. I still get the same error. I've read that it's a permissions issue but I'm just very lost.

Comment: The key you need on a server to connect to it should be the public key, not your private one; and it should be added to the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the user you want to connect with. This said, all those are server configurations issues and not programming issues, thus they do not fall under what is on-topic as described in the [help/on-topic], here.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your issue is your Amazon Security group (probably `default`).  That SG has to allow inbound traffic on port 22.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/security-groups.html

If you set up the VPC (Virtual Private Cloud), then you may not have a route to the outside world.  Try to log into one of your VMs via the AWS console, and see whether you can reach the outside world from that VM.